# Proving the distance formula in the Poincaré disk by integrating the line element

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

The line element on the Poincaré disk is given by

$$ds^2 = \frac{4\|dy\|^2}{(1-\|y\|^2)^2}.$$

I don't understand how to go from this line element to the equation

$$d(p, q) = \cosh\left(1 + 2\frac{\|p - q\|^2}{(1- \|p\|^2)(1-\|q\|^2)}\right)$$

where $p, q$ are two points in the Poincaré disk and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

I just can't seem to make the integral $\int ds$ work out algebraically.

**EDIT**:

So currently I have that $y_1 = (1-t)p_1 + tq_1$ and, assuming $p, q$ are on the x-axis, $y_2 = 0$. Then $dy = (q_1 - p_1) dt$, and so

$$\int ds = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{4 (q_1 - p_1)^2}{(1 - ((1-t)p_1 + tq_1)^2)^2}} dt = 2 |q_1 - p_1| \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - ((1-t)p_1 + tq_1)^2)^2}} dt$$

For the last integral Mathematica spits out

$$\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - ((1-t)p_1 + tq_1)^2)^2}} dt = \frac{\log \left((t-1) p_1-t q_1+1\right)-\log \left(-(t-1) p_1+t q_1+1\right)}{2
   \left(p_1-q_1\right)}$$

Comment: You can make a metric-preserving automorphism to put $p$ and $q$ on the real axis, in which case the integration becomes easy.

Comment: Even putting $p,q$ on the real line I get a nasty looking sum of log terms.

Comment: Please show us what you have when $0\le p<q<1$ are real.

Comment: BTW, you can "show us" by clicking "edit" below your question and adding your work.

Comment: A difference of logs, $\ln A - \ln B$, can be rewritten $\ln \frac{A}{B}$. Also: What you've got is an indefinite integral; it needs to be evaluated at $t = 1$ and at $t = 0$, and then you compute the difference of these two. I certainly don't see how this'll get you to the given formula, but at least it'll get you computing a number rather than a function of $t$.

Comment: BTW: Thanks for showing us your work!